# Calling native function from libexpect

Tags: tcl, expect, pexpect

I want to call native function from `libexpect`, specifically whenever there is an input. I can do it like this using `pexpect`.

```py
import pexpect
def f(input):
    # here I do whatever I want depending upon the input
    return input;
p=pexpect.spawn('bash')
p.interact(chr(29),input_filter=f)
```

Is something like this possible to do in `C` using `libexpect`? The manpage of `expect` states this:

```
interact [string1 body1] ... [stringn [bodyn]]
         gives control of the current process to the user,  so  that  key‐
         strokes  are  sent  to  the  current  process, and the stdout and
         stderr of the current process are returned.

         String-body pairs may be specified as arguments,  in  which  case
         the  body  is  executed when the corresponding string is entered.
         (By default, the string is not  sent  to  the  current  process.)
```

But, how will I call a `C` function from the body when using `libexpect`?

Comment: Completely off the top of my head, you'd have to write a tcl command in C that calls your C function. See https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/CrtCommand.html